# I am trying to run the following code for quicksort but the output is always a garbage value.What should be the modification in the code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

this is the following code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int findPivot(int a[],int startIndex,int endIndex)
{
    int pivot=a[endIndex];
    int pivotIndex=startIndex;
    for(int i=0;i<endIndex-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<pivot)
        {
            int temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[pivotIndex];
            a[pivotIndex]=a[i];
            pivotIndex++;
        }
    }

    int temp=pivot;//swapping pivot element into its position.
    pivot=a[pivotIndex];
    a[pivotIndex]=temp;
    return pivotIndex;
}

void quickSort(int a[],int startingIndex,int endingIndex)
{
    int number;
    if(startingIndex < endingIndex)
    {
        int returnValueOfPivot= findPivot(a,startingIndex,endingIndex);
        //cout<<returnValueOfPivot<<endl;
        quickSort(a,startingIndex,returnValueOfPivot-1);//sorting for left
        quickSort(a,returnValueOfPivot+1,endingIndex);//sorting for right
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number;
    cout<<"Enter the total number of elements"<<endl;
    cin>>number;
    cout<<"Enter the values"<<endl;
    int a[number-1];
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    quickSort(a,0,number-1);

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i]<<",";
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @CoryKramer thanks for the insight ,I will quickly run it by.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am currently using atom and it is not showing me any compile time errors

Comment: @Star.Kid: You are not trying to find a compiler error; you are trying to debug a logical bug. You should read Nathan's comment again and follow the link he gave you.

Comment: I was not talking about compiler errors.  A debugger lets you run the code and step through it line by line to see how it works.  Using that you can find most of your issues.

Comment: @Nathan Oliver I seem to have misunderstood your previous reply.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

There are three major problems in your code :

1. `int a[number-1];`
   You are allocating 1 less space for your array. Note that, array index starts from 0. So array of 5 numbers will be like

> `array[5] : array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3],array[4]`

2. Swapping array values :

> ```
> int temp=pivot;//swapping pivot element into its position.
> pivot=a[pivotIndex];
> a[pivotIndex]=temp;
> ```

Here, you swapped pivot value with a[pivotIndex] not a[endIndex]!!

So the correct swap would have been :

> ```
> int temp=a[endIndex];//swapping pivot element into its position.
> a[endIndex]=a[pivotIndex];
> a[pivotIndex]=temp;
> ```

3. `for(int i=0;i<endIndex-1;i++)` is incorrect loop

correct loop would be :

> `for(int i=startIndex;i<=endIndex-1;i++)`

You need to start from the `start index` and end **till** the `end index`. You are currently going from `0` to `end - 1`. [Think of the right side array loop, it won't start with 0]

Make these changes and your code will work.

Comment: Please, note that VLAs are not standard C++.

Comment: @Bob__ VLA? Sorry I dint get you.

Comment: With `cin >> n; arr[n];` you are declaring a Variable Length Array (n isn't const). This is Ok in C99, optional in C11, not standard (but allowed by some compilers like g++) in C++.

Comment: @Bob__ Ok got it. Thanks.